# How can I use oledb without error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have oledbconnection for mdb and oracle database, like this:

```
OleDbConnection Connection;
Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
                                 Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));

OleDbCommand Command1, Command2;

Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2", Connection);

Connection.Open();

var1 = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
var2 = (int)Command2.ExecuteScalar();

Connection.Close();
```

It's working great when can connect to database and select return value.

But when have a problem for connect to database or table does not exist, page getting error.

I use var1 and var2 in gridview and detailsview controls.

I need to open this page without error when connection problem or table does not exist. For example if page can't connect to database or table does not exist, var1 and var2 values can be 0. And page open without error.

Like this:

```
Connected? --> yes --> return any value oledbcommand? --> yes --> var1 = thisvalue

Connected? --> no --> var1 = 0

Connected? --> yes --> return any value? --> no(table does not exist etc.) --> var1 = 0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What error you get? What is the type of `d1` column? If it returns different then `int`, why do you cast it to `int` in first place? That does not make sense.

Comment: Can't connect database or it's not int value or table does not exist, etc... d1 is int.

Comment: Actually I need to control this connection. Connected, no problem, if can't connect, return static value for variable. Connected and return any value, no problem, if table does not exist or cant get any return, return static value for variable.

Comment: @Ric could you rewrite your question? I read it twice and still don't understand what exactly you are asking about

Comment: Garath, sorry for my english. I asking open my asp.net page without error. Oledbconnection sometimes getting error. Table does not exist or timeout or cant connect database etc. When I get any error about this connection, my page getting error. So I need to control this connection. If getting any error, my variables must be static value and my page open without any error(any connection error or any error because of variables)

Comment: Ric , so, you don't want to use try catch to avoid the two situation?

Comment: @Angus Chung, I want to use this connection if possible. If can't connect or table does not exist, skip it, return static value for variables.

Comment: Ric,you can set static value for variables in **catch** block.

Comment: @Angus Chung, how? Is it work without connection error?

Comment: Ric , i posted it , check if it works.

Comment: @Ric please use `try {..} catch(Exception){} finally {}` block instead of `try/catch` block.

Comment: @Selva TS, can you show me example for this? Thank you.

Comment: ok, Seleva TS , i will add it in my answer.

Comment: Otherwise use `using` statement instead of `try/catch/finally` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use **try catch** to make sure your page open without error.

```
    bool con = true;
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection Connection;
        Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
                                         Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));
        Connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand Command1, Command2;
        Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
        Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2", Connection);
        try
        {
            var1 = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
            var2 = (int)Command2.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            con = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Command1.Dispose();
            Command2.Dispose();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        con = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!con)
        {
            //put your static value here
            var1 = 1;
            var2 = 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by `using statement/try/catch` block.

```
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection Connection;
            using (Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
                                             Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb")))
            {
                OleDbCommand Command1, Command2;

                Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
                Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT d1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 2", Connection);

                Connection.Open();

                var1 = (int)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
                var2 = (int)Command2.ExecuteScalar();

                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Log your exception here
            var1 = 1;
            var2 = 2;
        }
```

The `using` statement internally deals with `Exception`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.120).aspx),

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, its work for me. I can't understand one thing: it's tried connection and executescalar, if any problem, skip everything and going to catch. Is there any way just skip commands that has problem? For example, connection is ok, var1 return value but var2 return error. It's skip var1 and var2 and going to catch. So is it possible going to catch for just error commands(for ex. just for var2)?